# How to slice JSON data in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, pagination

I have made 2 components 1)Content.js  2)Pagination.js
I want to display the content when user clicks on pagination component. There are total 16 objects per page. I have used `.slice(0,16)` method for page 1. Now I want to change the parameters passed in slice function based on page number eg:
`.slice(0,16)`    --> for page 1
`.slice(17,33)`   ---> for page 2
and so on till page 5 each page should display 16 objects per page and total 5 pages.

Content.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Matchinfo from './matchinfo';
import './content.css';

class Content extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            matches:[],
            loading:true,
            callmatchinfo: false,
            matchid:''
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('api/matches')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
      console.log(res)
      this.setState({
        matches:res.slice(0,16),     <----Parameters inside it must be changed for each page
        loading:false
      });
    })
    }

  viewstats(matchid){
    this.setState({
        callmatchinfo: true,
        matchid: matchid
    });
  }

  rendermatchinfo(){
    return <Matchinfo matchid={this.state.matchid} />
  }

    renderMatches() {
        return this.state.matches.map(match => {
            return (
                <div className="col-lg-3">
                    <div id="content">
                        <p className="match">MATCH {match.id}</p>
                        <h4>{match.team1}</h4>
                        <p>VS</p>
                        <h4>{match.team2}</h4>
                        <div className="winner">
                            <h3>WINNER</h3>
                            <h4>{match.winner}</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div className="stats">
                            <button type="button" onClick= {()=>{this.viewstats(match.id)}} className="btn btn-success">View Stats</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        })
    }

    render() {

        if (this.state.loading) {
            return <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Loading_icon.gif" />
        }
        else if(this.state.callmatchinfo){
        return <Matchinfo match_id={this.state.matchid} />
        }

    return (
      <div>
          <div className="row">
            {this.renderMatches()}
              </div>
          <div className="row">
            {this.state.callmatchinfo ? this.rendermatchinfo() : ''}
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Content;
```

Pagination.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Content from './content';

class Pagination extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <div className="container">                 
              <ul className="pagination">
                <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Pagination;
```

For more clarity see the screenshot of page 1.This functionality must be extended for  5 pages.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the `Pagination` component and attach an event like below :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Content from './content';

class Pagination extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <div className="container">                 
              <ul className="pagination">
                <li onClick={this.props.onPageNext.bind(this, 1)} ><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li onClick={this.props.onPageNext.bind(this, 2)} ><a href="#">2</a></li>
 <li onClick={this.props.onPageNext.bind(this, 3)} ><a href="#">3</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

export default Pagination;

In Content.js :

...

```
return (
      <div>
          <div className="row">
            {this.renderMatches()}
              </div>
          <div className="row">
            {this.state.callmatchinfo ? this.rendermatchinfo() : ''}
          </div>
            <Pagination onPageNext={this.onPageNext} /> 

      </div>
    );
```

...

```
  onPageNext(nextPage) {
    // logic to set the setState method for pagination...
  }
```

Comment: I could not get this line `export const Pagination = ({onPageNext})`

Comment: I am suggesting that you don't need 
class Pagination extends Component instead a dumb component like the one I have proposed will do the work

Comment: I could not understand what is dumb component but this is the hierarchy Content component -> pagination component -> home component. What I am trying to do is use state variables start and end initially start =0 and end =16 which must be passed inside `.slice(this.props.start,this.props.end)` and then onClick I just want to inject new parameters inside `.slice()` eg: if I click on page 2 it should inject start=17 and end= 33 how can I do it ?

Comment: @DimitarChristoff Did you got what I am trying to do here you can just check above comments. Can you suggest how can I do it using `this.props.start` and `this.end.props`

Comment: Dumb components don't have direct access to the app state. It only relies on data that you have passed as props, hence the name "dumb". Containers (smart components) gets its data directly from the app state.

Comment: updated please check, you can define onPageNext event method in your Content.js, and whenever click if fired on Pagination, that method will be triggered.